# facing error as soon as I load session library in my codeigniter 3.0.4 controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have seen and checked other stackoverflow questions and the common answer to this problem was

> make sure there's no whitespace before your `<?php` tag

Even after browsing other blogs and articles regarding this issue, I am still facing the same error. But if I remove the load of session, everything works normal.

my error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 117

Backtrace:

File: /home/content/97/8248497/html/dvjtest/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 9
Function: library

File: /home/content/97/8248497/html/dvjtest/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/97/8248497/html/dvjtest/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 568

Backtrace:

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Exception

Message: Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.

Filename: /home/content/97/8248497/html/dvjtest/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 119

Backtrace:

File: /home/content/97/8248497/html/dvjtest/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 9
Function: library

File: /home/content/97/8248497/html/dvjtest/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

my controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
    } 

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change (config/config.php line # 374 on Codeigniter 3.0.4)

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'NULL';
```

to

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH.'ci_sessions';
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Note

> If you’ve upgraded from a previous version of CodeIgniter and you
>   don’t have ‘**sess_save_path**’ configured, then the Session library will
>   look for the old ‘**sess_table_name**’ setting and use it instead. Please
>   don’t rely on this behavior as it will get removed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

session library is trying to write to disk which happens to involved mkdir() as well. You need to either make that path writeable or change session data directory to something else that is already writeable.

Check "sess_save_path" in configs. More documentation on session configs:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences